# Build controller cannot start after TFS 2012 Update 1

Tags: build-server, team-foundation-server

I just updated our TFS 2012 server to Update 1 (http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/downloads) via the web downloader.

The Web UI works great, SharePoint as well, the Source Control has no problems. It just seems that the build controller cannot start its service.

The error in the event viewer is the following:

```
One or more exceptions occurred while starting build machine vstfs:///Build/ServiceHost/24. See the ProcessExceptions property for more details.
Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.BuildEnvironment..ctor(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.HostEnvironmentOption, System.String, System.String)'.
Method not found: 'Void Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Workflow.BuildEnvironment..ctor(Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Client.HostEnvironmentOption, System.String, System.String)'.
```

Full Event XML is here: http://pastie.org/6231163

The MSDN documentation for the class that seems to be the problem is here: msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.workflow.buildenvironment.buildenvironment.aspx

And I'm simply assuming some DLL versioning is happening. But I don't know where to start or this problem has happened to anyone before.

We tried to uninstall and reinstall the feature in TFS, create a new build controller. Nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems unregistering the build service and registering it again after solved this problem.

We still have a problem with starting the service itself, but I will create another question for that.